# Selected Item not getting for a Listbox inside another Listbox item template

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a `PrimaryItems` List & foreach PrimaryItem there is a `SecondaryItems` list.So i used a `ListBox` as `ItempTemplate` of another `ListBox`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PrimaryItems}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SecondaryItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSecondaryItem}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

**My View Model Code**

```
    private List<PrimaryItem> _primaryItems;
    public List<PrimaryItem> PrimaryItems
    {
        get { return _primaryItems; }
        set { _primaryItems = value;RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    //SecondaryItems list is inside in each PrimaryItem
    //private List<SecondaryItem> _secondaryItems;
    //public List<SecondaryItem> SecondaryItems
    //{
       // get { return _secondaryItems; }
       // set { _secondaryItems = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    //}

    private SecondaryItem _selectedSecondaryItem;
    public SecondaryItem SelectedSecondaryItem
    {
        get { return _selectedSecondaryItem; }
        set 
        {
            _selectedSecondaryItem = value;
            if (_selectedSecondaryItem != null)
            {
                //TO DO
            }
        }
    }<br/>
```

This is the `class` structure

```
public class PrimaryItem
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<SecondaryItem> SecondaryItems{ get; set; }
}

public class SecondaryItem
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }  
}
```

and I set `SelectedItem` Binding to the `Second ListBox`.
But am not getting the Selection Trigger on `Second ListBox`.
Can we use a `ListBox` inside another ListBox` Template ?
 If yes how do we overcome this problem?

Comment: Show your `ViewModel`'s code

Comment: hi @Andrey Gordeev i added viewdel code.please check it.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` since it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

As far as I understand your requirements, `PrimaryItem` class should has a property `SecondaryItems`. So remove it from `ViewModel` and paste to `PrimaryItem` class (as well as `SelectedSecondaryItem` property):

```
private ObservableCollection<SecondaryItem> _secondaryItems;
public ObservableCollection<SecondaryItem> SecondaryItems
{
    get { return _secondaryItems; }
    set { _secondaryItems = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}
```

***EDIT:***

I've fully reproduced your situation and get it working.

*Classes:*

```
public class PrimaryItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SecondaryItem> SecondaryItems { get; set; }

    private SecondaryItem _selectedSecondaryItem;
    public SecondaryItem SelectedSecondaryItem
    {
        get { return _selectedSecondaryItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedSecondaryItem = value;

            if (_selectedSecondaryItem != null)
            { // My breakpoint here
                //TO DO
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SecondaryItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

*ViewModel:*

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<PrimaryItem> _primaryItems;
    public List<PrimaryItem> PrimaryItems
    {
        get { return _primaryItems; }
        set { _primaryItems = value; RaisePropertyChanged("PrimaryItems"); }
    }

    public ErrorMessageViewModel()
    {
        this.PrimaryItems = new List<PrimaryItem>
            {
                new PrimaryItem
                    {
                        SecondaryItems =
                            new List<SecondaryItem>
                                {
                                    new SecondaryItem { Id = 1, Name = "First" },
                                    new SecondaryItem { Id = 2, Name = "Second" },
                                    new SecondaryItem { Id = 3, Name = "Third" }
                                },
                        Name = "FirstPrimary",
                        Id = 1
                    }
            };
    }
}
```

*View:*

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.Views.MyView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestApp.ViewModels;assembly=TestApp.ViewModels"
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    Title="Title" Height="240" Width="270" ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" WindowStyle="ToolWindow">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MyViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PrimaryItems}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SecondaryItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSecondaryItem}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: yea it was my mistake .SecondaryItems list is inside every PrimaryItem. Even i changed the collection type  as 'ObservableCollection' am not getting the 'SelectedItem'

Comment: Is `SelectedSecondaryItem` property in `PrimaryItem` class?

Comment: No .SecondList is a Collection of SecondaryItem . So selectedItem of that list should be the type of SecondaryItem . So i used like that

Comment: No, I asked which class `SelectedSecondaryItem` belongs to?

Comment: hi i updated question with the class structure. Can you please check it ?

Comment: Move `public SecondaryItem SelectedSecondaryItem {get... set...}` from `ViewModel` to `PrimaryItem` class

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `LinqToVisualTree`, it can get alomost all `Control`s in your app, you just have to select what you want to find(in your case `ListBoxItem`), and then cast it to your model. I used it, when I needed to get text from  `TextBox` which was in `ListboxItem`. But it also fits to your task.

Comment: Can you share any link for refer?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62397/LINQ-to-Tree-A-Generic-Technique-for-Querying-Tree